# How to copy multiple xml files from nested subfolders into one unified folder

Tags: python-3.x

In python, how can I copy multiple xml files from a directory with thousands of sub and sub-sub folders into a unified directory where all xmls can be found?

xmls can be found in "mike / * / * /* /*.xml"
and output dist: for instance "alice/"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved using the built-in [pathlib module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html). Use the `rglob` method to search for files recursively in a given directory.

```
from pathlib import Path

path_dir_origin = Path('mike')
path_dir_destination = Path('alice')
path_dir_destination.mkdir(exist_ok=True)

for path_xml_origin in path_dir_origin.rglob('*.xml'):
    path_xml_destination = path_dir_destination.joinpath(path_xml_origin.name)
    path_xml_destination.write_text(path_xml_origin.read_text())
```

EDIT:

Since OP encountered problems copying the xml-files, it might be wise to use shutils for the copying.

```
from pathlib import Path
from shutil import copyfile

path_dir_origin = Path('mike')
path_dir_destination = Path('alice')
path_dir_destination.mkdir(exist_ok=True)

for path_xml_origin in path_dir_origin.rglob('*.xml'):
    path_xml_destination = path_dir_destination.joinpath(path_xml_origin.name)
    copyfile(path_xml_origin, path_xml_destination)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot although it worked but at some point it broke:

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa9 in position 5454: invalid start byte

Comment: @MikeFelan I'm not familiar with the xml format. Try: `path_xml_destination.write_bytes(path_xml_origin.read_bytes())`